# How can I map helm-projectile-grep to helm-projectile-ag?

Tags: helm, projectile

I want to replace helm-projectile-grep with helm-projectile-ag without using default binding (C-c p s s).

For example if I use helm-projectile-switch-project (C-c p p), then in the helm window I press C-s, then it will invoke helm-projectile-grep, but I want to use helm-projectile-ag instead because it's faster. I don't know what other search action will invoke helm-projectile-grep, but whenever I call the function, I want it to call helm-projectile-ag instead. Is it possible, how can I map it in my .emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to redefine `helm-projectile-grep` to meet your need. In order to avoid confusion, use [Advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) instead of a plain `defun` here:

```
(define-advice helm-projectile-grep (:override (&optional dir) ag)
  (helm-do-ag (or dir (projectile-project-root))))
```

The `define-advice` macro was added to Emacs recently, if you don't have it, then use `advice-add`. Since Emacs can advice a function without know it, you can put this anywhere in your Emacs initialization file.

Comment: advice seems nice, never heard of it before. Thanks!

Comment: If you're only after `C-c p p` you can also change it's behaviour with `(helm-delete-action-from-source "Grep in projects `C-s'" helm-source-projectile-projects)` and `(helm-add-action-to-source "Grep in projects `C-s'" 'helm-do-ag helm-source-projectile-projects 4)`